# Rewrite method to prevent SQL Injection NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I need to rewrite this method to use parameterized queries in NHibernate:

```
static public int GetDomainId(string domainName)
    {
        string hql = string.Format("select domain.{0} from {2} domain where {1}='{3}'", RO_ID, DOM_NM, "DOMAIN", domainName);
        using (NHibernate.ISession session = NHibernate.NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession())
        {
            NHibernate.IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql);
            IList<int> ids = query.List<int>();
            if (ids.Count == 1)
            {
                return ids[0];
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I've updated the method to use the following parameters:

```
static public int GetDomainRoId1(string domainName)
    {
        string hql = "select domain.:param1 from DOMAIN domain where :param2=:param3";
        using (NHibernate.ISession session = NHibernate.NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession())
        {
            NHibernate.IQuery query = session.CreateSQLQuery(hql)
                .SetParameter("param1", DOM_RO_ID)
                .SetParameter("param2", DOM_DOM_NM)
                .SetString("param3", domainName)
                .ExecuteUpdate();

            IList<int> ids = query.List<int>();
            if (ids.Count == 1)
            {
                return ids[0];
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

But this is throwing an error in the code: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'NHibernate.IQuery'"

Could someone please help me correct this? 
But also point me in the direction of a tutorial to help me better understand how NHibernate works.

Comment: what is the result of `ExecuteUpdate`? that *sounds* like it is executing the thing expecting it to be an `ExecuteNonQuery` style - are you sure you should have that line? is there not an `ExecuteQuery` method or similar?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the replies. I was able to get this working by changing session.CreateSQLQuery(hql) to session.CreateQuery(hql)

```
static public int GetDomainRoId1(string domainName)
    {
        string hql = "select domain.:param1 from DOMAIN domain where :param2=:param3";
        using (NHibernate.ISession session = NHibernate.NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession())
        {
            NHibernate.IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql)
                .SetParameter("param1", DOM_RO_ID)
                .SetParameter("param2", DOM_DOM_NM)
                .SetString("param3", domainName)
                //.ExecuteUpdate();

            IList<int> ids = query.List<int>();
            if (ids.Count == 1)
            {
                return ids[0];
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```